# SINGLE supported beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Let's say I have a beam supported exactly in the middle (like a seesaw) and a distributed force applied on it across the beam. What is the way to calculate the displacement, moment, shear...etc of the beam?

Comment: What have you considered so far? Show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the symmetry, you have zero slope over the support and if you draw the FBD at the support you see it is like a cantilever beam with half of the length of the beam.

Let's call the uniformly distributed load $w$ and length $2L$ for convenience.

$$ M_{max}=\frac{wL^2}{2} \; and\; V{max}= 2wL  $$

Maximum moment and shear happen over the support.

I let you draw the moment and shear diagrams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but doesn't the moment and shear should be twice as large? because the point is experiencing moment and shear from both sides. and how do I calculate the stress in this position?